# How to send key, value messages with the kafka console producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I got a use case where I need to send key value messages with Kafka Console Producer. So how to achieve this through the `kafka-console-producer` command?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I found out the solution after some research and the solution is here.

***kafka-console-producer command***

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic topic-name --property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=:"
```

After running this command you will enter in producer console and from there you can send key, value messages.

For example

```
key1:value1
key2:value2
key3:value3
```

For more clarity, I am providing sample key-value message here, `emp_info` is a key and `JSON object` is a value.

```
emp_info: {"emp_id":100,"first_name":"Keshav","last_name":"Lodhi","designation":"DataEngineer"}
```

**Note:** Simply sending lines of text will result in messages with `null` keys. In order to send messages with both `keys and values` you must set the `parse.key` and `key.separator` properties on the command line when running the producer.

Comment: How do I only send 1 message? When I enter the key-value pair, it expects the next line. How do I tell it that I just want to send 1 message?

Comment: If you want to send only one message, send it from a file which has that one message.. Syntax  kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic topic-name --property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=:"  < filePathAndName

Comment: In my experience, the `"` characters surrounding the `--property` params are only mandatory if you want to use a special character as the value of the property. In my case I wanted to use `|` as the `key.separator` and I could only make it work like this: `--property "key.separator=|"`. Thanks for this response.

Comment: @SAKURA No, it is not "expecting" the next line. The producer CLI is for sending messages, one per line. When you hit the Enter key, that line will be sent immediately. If you are done, press `Ctrl+C` to terminate the process. You can read this on the official quick start page.

Comment: default keySeparator is "\t" (tab). https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleProducer.scala#L292

Comment: @SAKURA just use control+d to finish sending message.

Comment: for me didn't work using a ":" separator, I needed to use ";"

Answer (score 9):

By default, the producer doesn’t care about the topic-partition on which the messages are written to and will balance the messages fairly over all the partitions of a topic. Producer picks the partition based on the hash of the record’s key or in round-robin fashion if the record has no key.

1. Kafka uses the key to specify the target partition. The default
   strategy is to choose a partition based on a hash of the key or use
   round-robin algorithm if the key is null.
2. Kafka works with key-value pairs, if key not specified, it will be considered default as null and partition will identified as round-robin fashion.
3. If we specify key, messages/records with same key goes to same partition
4. To enable sending full key-value pairs, from the command-line, we    need to use two properties as below:
5. properties

- parse.key : if it’s true – key is mandatory, by default it’s set as
  false.
- key.separator : as below

Examples:

- key.separator=,
- key.separator=-
- key.separator=:

Kafka Console Producer command

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list MY-KAFKA:29092 --topic kafka-prod --property parse.key=true --property key.separator=,
```

Reference: https://shashirl9.medium.com/kafka-producer-internals-d971ac582688